# Symbols in left gutter of editor ("gutter icons")

Tags: android, android-studio

In Android Studio 2.1.1 there are lots of icons and symbols that appear in the left margin (left gutter) of the Editor Window.

1. Where can I see a comprehensive list of what these symbols/icons mean?
2. How do I turn them on or off?  Other places on the web said that I could access them via "Settings, Editor, General, Gutter Icons" but I don't see that in my version of Android Studio.

Comment: "Where can I see a comprehensive list of what these symbols/icons mean?" -- there cannot be one, as some, such as drawable resources, are app-specific. In general, if there are any that lack a tooltip explanation, file a bug report.

Answer (score 2):

The gutter icons can be found in Settings > Editor > General > Gutter Icons.  These icons come from the IntelliJ editor.
[Click to view Settings in Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdiWQ.jpg)
You can turn individual icons on and off using these settings.